# Multiturn conversation + nested dialog Bot with Langchain and OpenAI

Tags: bots, openai-api, langchain

Currently exploring Langchain and OpenAI.
Is it possible to use Langchain and OpenAI only to build a multiturn conversation + nested dialog like below's example? At the end, we also want to get the name, email and feedback. This can be done with MS Bot Framework, just wandering if it can be done with LangChain and OpenAI.

```
User: I want to submit a feedback
Bot: Sure, can I have your name?
User: My name is Alex
Bot: Can I have your email?
User: My email is alex@gmail.com
Bot: May I get your feedback
User: lorem lorem lorem 
Bot: Would you like to leave your phone number?

User: No
    Bot: Okay, let me know if you need anything else.
User: Yes, 023232323123123
    Bot: Thanks. , let me know if you need anything else.
```